Difficulty reading and modifying a csv file in a Sockets, Threads and Mutexes Project
My name is Luís and I am currently developing a project that consists of implementing a client/server system to manage mobility services offered by the company ServiMoto. Services include tree and garden checks, fire service interventions, postal deliveries and pizza delivery. The system allows clients (bikes) to connect to the server to receive tasks, update task status and request new tasks. The server manages these requests, allocates tasks to clients, and keeps records of the allocated tasks and clients in CSV files. The project is implemented in C# using sockets and the defined communication protocol.
Currently my two main codes are these:
class Server:
// Object Mutex to ensure exclusive access to CSV files
static Mutex mutex = new Mutex();

// Method to update the CSV file with the completion of a task
static void UpdateCompletedTask(string fileName, string taskId)
{
    // Locks the mutex to ensure exclusive access
    mutex.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            if (lines[i].StartsWith(taskId))
            {
                // Replaces "in progress" with "completed" only if "in progress" is present
                if (lines[i].Contains("in progress"))
                {
                    lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("in progress", "completed");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Releases the mutex
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}

// Method to assign a new task to the client and update the corresponding CSV file
static void AllocateNewTask(string fileName, string clientId)
{
    // Locks the mutex to ensure exclusive access
    mutex.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        // Logic to assign a new task to the client and update the CSV file
        // For example, it may involve reading the file to find an available task and updating its status
    }
    finally
    {
        // Releases the mutex
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}

// Server IP address and port
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
int port = 8888;

// Starts the server and listens for connections
server = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
server.Start();

Console.WriteLine("Server started...");

// Accepts client connection
TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");

// Prepares network streams
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
byte[] data = new byte[256];
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

int bytesRead;

// Reads data received from the client
while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)) != 0)
{
    response.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead));
    Console.WriteLine("Received message: {0}", response.ToString());

    // Checks the type of received message
    if (response.ToString().StartsWith("CONNECT"))
    {
        // Responds with success
        byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("100 OK");
        stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Response sent: 100 OK");
    }
    else if (response.ToString().StartsWith("TASK_COMPLETE"))
    {
        // Extracts the ID of the completed task
        string completedTaskId = response.ToString().Substring("TASK_COMPLETE".Length).Trim();
        // Updates the corresponding CSV file
        UpdateCompletedTask("Service_A.csv", completedTaskId);
        // Responds with task completion confirmation
        byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("TASK_COMPLETED");
        stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Response sent: TASK_COMPLETED");
    }
    else if (response.ToString() == "REQUEST_TASK")
    {
        // Logic to assign a new task to the client and update the CSV file
        // Here you can call the AllocateNewTask() method to assign the new task
    }
    else if (response.ToString() == "QUIT")
    {
        // Responds with connection closure
        byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("400 BYE");
        stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Response sent: 400 BYE");

        // Closes the connection
        client.Close();
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        // Responds with error
        byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ERROR");
        stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Response sent: ERROR");
    }

    // Clears the StringBuilder for the next message
    response.Clear();
}


and now the client class:
// Server IP address and port
string serverIp = "127.0.0.1";
int port = 8888;

// Creates an instance of the TCP client
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverIp, port);
Console.WriteLine("Connected to server...");

// Prepares network streams
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
byte[] data = new byte[256];
string response = string.Empty;

Console.WriteLine("Enter your Client ID: ");
string clientId = Console.ReadLine();

// Sends connection message
string connectMessage = "CONNECT";
byte[] connectMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(connectMessage);
stream.Write(connectMsg, 0, connectMsg.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Message sent: {0}", connectMessage);

// Reads the server's response
int bytesReceived = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesReceived);
Console.WriteLine("Response received: {0}", response);

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Choose an option:");
    Console.WriteLine("1. Complete task");
    Console.WriteLine("2. Request new task");
    Console.WriteLine("3. Quit");
    Console.Write("Option: ");
    string option = Console.ReadLine();

    switch (option)
    {
        case "1":
            // Sends task completion message
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the ID of the completed task: ");
            string completedTaskId = Console.ReadLine();
            string completionMessage = $"TASK_COMPLETE <{completedTaskId}>";
            byte[] completionMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(completionMessage);
            stream.Write(completionMsg, 0, completionMsg.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent: {0}", completionMessage);

            // Reads the server's response
            int completionBytesReceived = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, completionBytesReceived);
            Console.WriteLine("Response received: {0}", response);
            break;

        case "2":
            // Sends request for new task
            string requestMessage = "REQUEST_TASK";
            byte[] requestMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestMessage);
            stream.Write(requestMsg, 0, requestMsg.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent: {0}", requestMessage);

            // Reads the server's response
            int requestBytesReceived = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, requestBytesReceived);
            Console.WriteLine("Response received: {0}", response);
            break;

        case "3":
            // Sends quit message
            string quitMessage = "QUIT";
            byte[] quitMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(quitMessage);
            stream.Write(quitMsg, 0, quitMsg.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent: {0}", quitMessage);

            // Reads the server's response
            int quitBytesReceived = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, quitBytesReceived);
            Console.WriteLine("Response received: {0}", response);

            // Closes the connection and exits the loop
            client.Close();
            return;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid option.");
            break;
    }
}


The problem is that when I want to declare a task completed using my UpdateCompletedTask function, the csv file does not change, and always remains the same. Can anyone help me?
I changed the code of my function a few times because I think the problem is in the UpdateCompletedTask function but still nothing changed.

I think the WaitOne is causing issue.  Where to you set/reset the WaitOne?

Honestly, there is so much wrong with the above code, it's hard to know where to start. Issues I can see: Use of files instead of a proper database. Use of TCP on localhost instead of a more performant protocol such as Named Pipes or Shared Memory. Lack of using to dispose objects that need disposing. Lack of async await. Blocking while the TCP stream is open. Not allowing multiple connections (by handing off the TcpClient). Use of Ascii instead of UTF8 or UTF16. Assumtption that exactly one Write results in exactly one Read on the other side, and lack of message framing.  ....

.... Many performance issues as well. Socket programming is hard, and has a huge amount of pitfalls. For these and many other reasons, you shouldn't roll your own protocol. Use an existing one, such as HTTP, SignalR or gRPC.

and keeps records of the allocated tasks and clients in CSV files - erk. Why!?  It's like you've said to yourself "how can I make this work as hard as possible for myself? I know, I'll roll my own everything; database, comms, RPC... Maybe in a few decades if I get time I'll write my own operating system to run it all on"

My guess would be that lines[i].StartsWith(taskId) never returns true. Maybe because your ids are enclosed in tags, i.e. <42>? This should be very easy to find with a debugger.

Set a breakpoint in UpdateCompletedTask. Is it reached at all?
Does taskId and lines look as expected?
Is lines[i].Replace("in progress", "completed") reached?

While you can probably make something like this work with enough effort, there are lots of problematic things in your code. Especially your reliance on strings, this can easily hide problems that could be caught by the compiler if proper types where used.
As others have mentioned, there are better ways to do things:
Network communication
Using a network stream for communication is difficult, see Stephen clearys TCP FAQ for all the things you need to do. Especially the part about the message framing.
But luck have it you do not need to do this yourself. There are a wide variety of higher level protocols, and libraries using these protocols. And these tend to be much easier to use, since you can send messages, or objects, not just streams of bytes. A request-response based protocol like http or gRPC sounds most suitable for your use case.
Storage
While a plain text/csv file can sometimes serve as an erzats database, using a real database will likely save you time and effort in the long run.
There are free full featured databases like postgres, or somewhat simpler in process databases like SQLite. In either case it is common to use an Object Relational Mapper (ORM) that converts between database rows and objects for you. Entity framework (EF) is probably the most popular choice.
I would personally do this as a ASP.Net webapi project (i.e. http) with a SQLite backend accessed thru EF. There should be plenty of tutorials and other resources on how to set this up.
